# Two interfaces, two addresses, two gateways?

Tags: debian, networking, ipv4

I have a system that has two network interfaces with different IP adresses, both of which are in the public address range (albeit via NAT in the case of the first one) and both of which have different gateways. (Long story, it's for testing purposes)

The problem is that right now, if I try to ping the address on the second interface, the default route points out via the first interface - and never arrives properly.

Is it possible to make sure that responses always go out over the same network interface (and with the same source IP) as they came in on? And if so, how?

Comment: Possibly some variant on this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the problem. Not every packet is a response and not every packet can be matched to some other packet such that "same network interface as they came in on" makes sense. What you want to do is select the gateway for a packet based on its source IP address.

This is called source-based routing or policy routing. You can do it with a [simple `iptables` rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming/4421#4421), but the best way is to set up two routing tables, one for each public source address:

First, create two tables (Replace <NAME1> and <NAME2> with sensible names for your two providers, same with IP1, DEV1, and so on):

```
echo 200 <NAME1> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo 201 <NAME2> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Add a gateway to each routing table (if needed):

```
ip route add <NET1> dev <DEV1> src <SRC1> table <NAME1>
ip route add <NET2> dev <DEV2> src <SRC2> table <NAME2>
```

Then a default route:

```
ip route add default via <IP1> table <NAME1>
ip route add default via <IP2> table <NAME2>
```

Then the rules to select the route table based on the source address:

```
ip rule add from <IP1> table <NAME1>
ip rule add from <IP2> table <NAME2>
```

See [Routing for multiple uplinks/providers](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) for more details.

Comment: You wrote: 'Not every packet is a response and not every packet can be matched to some other packet such that "same network interface as they came in on" makes sense. ' Can you explain this further? I understand, that not every packet is a response and not every packet can be matched to another "source" packet. If we exclude these packets from consideration, because they don't cause any problems and therefore do not concern us, why the packets remaining cannot be routed to the "same network interface as they came in on"?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh That wouldn't solve all of the problem. In particular, it would break whenever an outbound packet originated locally (such as an outbound ping request) went out the wrong interface for its source IP address and was dropped by the gateway. The problem is, as I explained, actually about making sure that packets go out the gateway corresponding to their source IP address.

Comment: David, I want to achieve the same thing as OP but I'm unable to. I've posted a question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/992624/vpn-client-doesnt-have-internet-connection, would be great if you could take a look

Answer (score 6):

David Schwartz's answer is excellent, but you can simplify the routing rules a bit by having just one extra table, and using your default route for the other. I have a server that's behind two NAT gateways, and I recently went through the process of recreating that scenario between a bunch of VMs. My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.13.13
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up ip route add table optus default via 192.168.13.10
    up ip rule add from 192.168.13.213 table optus
    up ip route add default via 192.168.13.11

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.13.213
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

(this is for a setup where the two ISPs are Optus and iiNet, hence the table name of 'optus')

This, plus the line in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` creating the table, should be all you need. You'll have two IP addresses; traffic from 192.168.13.13 will go out via 192.168.13.11, and traffic from 192.168.13.213 will go out via 192.168.13.10. Configure those two gateways to do their port forwarding appropriately (192.168.13.11 forwards stuff to 192.168.13.13, and 192.168.13.10 forwards stuff to 192.168.13.213), and the rest should take care of itself.

You may need to tweak things a bit for your situation, as you're using public IPs directly, but something like this should still work. Also, it's a lot easier to do these things in `/etc/network/interfaces` and then git-manage that file, rather than try to remember how you had it set up, two years later when the system has to be rebooted!

Answer (score 3):

**Dual network example**

This example is showing how an additional `eth1` with `10.130.0.2` netmask `255.255.255.255` and the gateway `10.130.0.1` can be made available to services that bind to it like `ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8`

Technically we are:

- Adding an other gateway with a greater metric
- Adding/using the table 100 and setting it up
- Adding a rule to route traffic to/from eth1 through it

```
ip addr add 10.130.0.2/32 broadcast 10.130.0.2 dev eth1
ip link set eth1 up
ip route add 10.130.0.1 src 10.130.0.2 dev eth1
ip route add 10.130.0.1 src 10.130.0.2 dev eth1 table 100
ip route add default via 10.130.0.1 dev eth1 metric 10
ip route add default via 10.130.0.1 dev eth1 table 100
ip rule add from 10.130.0.2/32 table 100
ip rule add to 10.130.0.2/32 table 100
curl --interface eth1 ifconfig.co
curl --interface eth0 ifconfig.co
ping -I eth1 8.8.8.8
```