# Specifying outgoing interface for SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a machine with two public IP addresses on two interfaces. This machine is running `sshd`. Is there a way to specify, when creating a tunnel with a SOCKS interface (i.e. `-D`), which interface to use for outgoing connections?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/243955/opensshds-dynamic-proxy-routing-capability-tunnel

Comment: technically that's not an sshd question, since once the packet exits the tunnel into the remote machine's IP stack, it's at the mercy of the routing table on that machine, subject to modification by any ipf/iptables rules that may be in place.  i'd tag this question with whatever firewall type your remote system uses, and I bet you can find an answer, even if it's as simple as adding specific routing table entries for specific destinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can solve your problem by a combination of the -b option in ssh, as suggested by mgjk, and routing. Suppose you are trying to build a tunnel to the site 8.8.8.7 (just a fictitious example), and you want the connection to go through eth1, then the command

```
 sudo route add -host 8.8.8.7 dev eth1
```

will add a proper route, and all should be well.

However, this is also the perfect case of application for "policy routing". It entails configuring the routing table on the machine setting up the tunnel (*i.e.* the one on which the command *ssh -D ...* is issued) simply because it's the only one on which the two interfaces exist.

A concise yet sufficient explanation is given by David Schwartz [on this very site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/two-interfaces-two-addresses-two-gateways). Only important detail is: say eth0 is 192.168.1.2, and eth1 is 10.0.0.2, then you may say

```
 ip rule add from 10.0.0.2 table <NAME1>
 ip rule add from 192.168.1.2 table <NAME2>
```

At this point, you can bind your ssh connection via -b to eth1's address, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use -b?

```
 -b bind_address
         Use bind_address on the local machine as the source address of
         the connection.  Only useful on systems with more than one
         address.
```

Comment: But I want to specify the source address of connections on the *remote* machine. I tried `-b` but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You can do per flow routing, can't you? On remote machine make a rule in your firewall configuration to use specific gateway. (It works with OpenBSD's PF http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/pools.html#outgoing, so I guess there should be a way to do it with Linux iptables).