# ip route match multiple fields

Tags: linux, routing

I have a Linux machine set up to forward IPv4 packets. I'm looking to do this:

> if packet matches both source **and** destination, forward to GW X.

How do I specify the source field? Do I need to use `iptables`?

Comment: What have you done so far?  How many interfaces does the machine have?

Comment: This is called source based routing. This answer does something close to what you're trying to do: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22794/4358