# Can I assign a virtual interface of wireless to a network namespace?

Tags: routing, network-namespaces, iw

I am trying to make a VPN router while keeping the host itself accessing Internet without VPN. The host has only one NIC which is wireless. So I have added two virtual interfaces via `iw phy phy0 interface add xxxxx`. One (wlan0_sta) as station to connect wireless to Internet. The other (wlan0_ap) as AP to connect clients. Also a wireguard device (wg0) as VPN endpoint. hostapd and iptables were involved.

Now every part worked, except data from clients were routed to wlan0_sta, instead of wg0. So I planned to have wlan0_ap and wg0 in a separated network namespace to make the routing work. But I found that `iw` cannot put virtual interface into network namespace. Only a "phy" can be put into network namespace.

So what should I do?

Comment: In order to achieve what you desire, you do not need a network namespace, but you need to learn what *policy routing* is. Try this, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22794/49626, then ask again.

Comment: I think [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/)'s pages have a clever use of built-in mark and `ip rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0` to force traffic into the tunnel (which is anyway policy routing as MariusMatutiae tells): [Wireguard Routing & Network Namespaces - Improved Rule-based Routing](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#improved-rule-based-routing). Other solutions might be available in that page, like having a dedicated network namespace for *all* physical interfaces thus compatible with your wifi setup.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, thanks. That is harder than I thought. I have not succeeded yet....

Comment: @A.B, yes, that was read. I have not got rule based routing working. So I tried the namespace solution, which falled into this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably no, at least as in Linux kernel version 4.9 for nl80211-based drivers.

---

**Update**: now you can usually reassign wlans to other network namespace, but in a somewhat roundabout way: you need to move a `phy` first, using a other tool.

```
iw phy phy0 set netns 16747
```

`/sys` needs to be mounted in the source network namespace.