# sysctl parameter for correct ARP response

Tags: sysctl, arp

I have a server that has some VMs, but the VMs can't communicate properly with the server because the server has several interfaces, and it responds on the wrong one.

**Q**: We know that there is a kernel parameter that can ensure that ARP responses will come only from that interface where the request went. What is that `sysctl` setting?

Server is Debian machine.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/834519/67675

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to execute:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter=1
```

This can be useful reading: [Multiple network interfaces and ARP flux](http://wiki.openvz.org/Multiple_network_interfaces_and_ARP_flux)

Comment: this will be only permament if I edit "/etc/sysctl.conf"?

Comment: from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt :

arp_filter - BOOLEAN / 1 - Allows you to have multiple network interfaces on the same subnet, In other words it allows control of which cards (usually 1) will respond to an arp request. / 0 - (default) The kernel can respond to arp requests with addresses from other interfaces. This may seem wrong but it usually makes sense, because it increases the chance of successful communication.