# Multiple routes to remote network, send response out same interface as request?

Tags: ip, routing, route, iproute

I have the following host, with one interface and two GRE tunnels. It thinks it is locally connected to three networks.

```
eth0:
 inet 10.1.0.123/16
gre1:
 inet 172.16.0.123/16
gre2:
 inet 192.168.0.123/16
```

The two GRE tunnels both have connections to a fourth network `10.0.0.0/16` (this is unrelated to eth0's network). I'd like to configure the routing tables on this host such that requests from the `10.0.0.0/16` network that come in via `gre1` to `172.16.0.123/16` are responded to via `gre1` as well. And vice-versa for the `gre2` tunnel.

- If I don't configure a route for `10.0.0.0/16`, then the packets are filtered due to `rp_filter`.
- If I disable `rp_filter` but don't configure a route for `10.0.0.0/16` then the response packets go out `eth0` due to the `default` route.
- I can set a route to `10.0.0.0/16` to either `gre1` or `gre2`, but I can't set them both.

```
$ sudo ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 dev gre2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Comment: The usual way to deal with multiple parallel routes is to give them priorities, so that the route with higher priority is always used. If you don't want to follow this pattern for whatever reason (you didn't say), them simplest solution would be to put both gre1 and gre2 in a network namespace of it's own, and have services answering requests run in both namespaces. Other solutions may be better depending on what you actually want to achieve (please also read about [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), Y = I need two parallel tunnels, X = ?).

Comment: It's still possible to use policy/source-based routing to do this without namespaces, *but* if the host's server application is over UDP rather than TCP, extra care must be done, sometimes in the application's configuration, sometimes in the application code (because an application not binding its source UDP address to emit a reply and not multi-homing aware itself may still get the system to choose the wrong interface and source address: the default). All this anyway only if different host's addresses are used (gre's interface ips) else this requires marks and gets worse.

Comment: @A.B Would you have an example of how to do this with policy-based routing?

Comment: @dirkt "for whatever reason" - Because of stateful firewalls in the `gre1` and `gre2` networks mucking with things. Middleboxes being middleboxes. The syn,ack looks unsolicited and gets eaten by a firewall if it takes a different return path. This isn't so much an XY question as it's a "someone is paying me to deal with crappy networks" question.

Comment: My comment asked for 2 questions: ip addresses and udp usage. Knowing an answer won't work correctly doesn't make me want to give one. I'm also curious about dirkt's question: he asked why you are using two tunnels, but you answered why you need to use the same tunnel because of firewalls.

Comment: So if someone is paying you, tell them "the way you set up things doesn't work, it would make more sense to change it". You can use policy based routing (see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming)), but as the other comment has said, it doesn't work properly in all situations. You'll always end up having to fiddle and fix things.